# Sidekiq Circular Dependency Error only when performing async

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circular-dependency, sidekiq

I am currently experiencing an issue where I get a Circular Dependency error raised using Sidekiq in my Rails app.  This only gets raised when using `perform_async`, otherwise it runs successfully.

Here's a simplified demo of the problem.

Sidekiq Worker:

```
# app/workers/normalize_fsbo_worker.rb

class NormalizeFSBOWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(property_id)
    puts property_id
  end
end
```

Raketask:

```
# lib/tasks/normalize.rake

require 'rake'
namespace :hh do
    namespace :normalize do
        desc "Async normalize all fsbo"
        task :fsbo_properties => [:environment] do |t, args|
          Property.where('fsbo IS NULL').find_in_batches do |group|
            group.each do |property|
              NormalizeFSBOWorker.perform_async(property.id) # Circular Dependency error
              # NormalizeFSBOWorker.new.perform(property.id)   # Works
            end
          end
        end
    end
end
```

Console:

```
$ be rake hh:normalize:fsbo_properties
```

Sidekiq log Stacktrace:

```
2014-05-21T16:19:48Z 4627 TID-osxsorcmw WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"NormalizeFSBOWorker", "args"=>[3120], "jid"=>"c84212e827ba1185794cab62", "enqueued_at"=>1400689188.5927122}
2014-05-21T16:19:48Z 4627 TID-osxsorcmw WARN: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant NormalizeFSBOWorker
2014-05-21T16:19:48Z 4627 TID-osxsorcmw WARN: /home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:460:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `const_missing'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:46:in `process'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
/home/lucas/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

So what's going on? Where is this circular reference and why would it not be raised with a `#new.perform`?

Comment: What is the file path to the `NormalizeFSBOWorker`?

Comment: @nort updated with filepaths

Comment: It appears this problem was discussed around https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1281